# How do you identify settling cracks versus structural cracks (new build )

Tags: walls, garage

In my new build house I've found roof to ground stucco crack on outside and at same location on inside (garage). There's a crack from top through the mortar, then straight through two blocks, then down joint in the wall.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If bricks and cinder blocks are breaking, that's a concern.  I would bring in a knowledgeable third party to assess it and determine the cause.  Then deal with the builder to get it fixed.

Comment: Thanks , i. Think i’ll Look for a structural engineer

Comment: Willie, please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how this site works. If you don't intend to follow up with your post, please consider deleting it. Unresolved posts are ugly.

Comment: @isherwood, your comment might be premature.  Willie's comment just indicates a next step.  There's not much other possible response at this point, and no other input to respond to.  Hopefully, he'll update the question when he has additional information, or close the loop if there's something definitive.

Comment: settling cracks are structural cracks, but that aside;what kind of house is this? can we have a full broadside photo of this wallfull front to back, and then the front too. What is the lay of the land? Has there been any events that could explain this? (California??) Where do you live?

Answer (score 2):

Several things are occurring here: 1) cracks through the blocks not just mortar joints, 2) vertical and diagonal cracks

1) In construction, block walls are designed with mortar joints to be weaker than concrete blocks. That way, when the building settles (and all buildings settle) the wall will zig zag crack down the wall in the mortar joint, NOT through a block. Replacing a block is much harder that repointing the mortar.

Your mason has screwed up and caused a big problem that can only be fixed by replacing the cracked blocks.

2) Generally, vertical cracks are caused by the foundation settling in one location and a diagonal crack is caused by the foundation settling along many feet (big area).

They are both “structural” cracks, it’s just that one is a bigger deal than another. A small crack (like yours) is called a “hair-line” crack and is minor. Often the building is constructed so fast that the foundation does not have a chance to settle before the final finishes have been installed. I think this is what happened to you.

I’d monitor it by drawing a line across the crack every 4’ or so, number the lines, and measure and photo each crack. I’d keep a journal for 1 year checking at regular intervals, say on the 1st of each month. If it continues to get bigger, you have a problem.

Likewise, if any cracks develop, note and monitor it too. If crack gets to be more than 3/16”, you have s problem. Let your contractor know what you’re going to do and send him notes and pics each month. Let him know you expect the cracked blocks replaced at the end of 1 year, plus and walls with cracks larger than 3/16”. (Check your warranty and make sure you send certified letter before the warranty ends.  Maybe this will be a 10 month monitoring process instead of 1 year.)

Answer (score 0):

I once heard a rule of thumb, that if you can get a finger in it then it's something to worry about. No on intended.